# how to get rid of tr_db.log in uvm-1.2?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

By default, UVM-1.2 generates a file "tr_db.log".

It is quite inconvenient to run long simulations while
generating this file.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, UVM 1.2 logs all transactions to a text-file (default name: `tr_db.log`).  The intention is that the vendor implementations will provide a different transaction logging mechanism that integrates with their database and permits transactions to be displayed on the waveform viewer and suchlike.

The API for transaction recording is defined by the `uvm_tr_database` class in `distrib/src/base/uvm_tr_database.svh`.

It would be relatively simple to create a derived class called `uvm_null_tr_database` that simply does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you continue to use UVM 1.1d. UVM 1.2 is still in the review process for people to provide feedback as the hand the standard over to the IEEE. One of the problems with UVM 1.2 is that it is not 100% backward compatible with UVM 1.1d, and if you have Verification IP from using UVM 1.1d, it may not work without modification.

You should not be getting this file if you are using the pre-compiled version of the UVM that comes with your tool. Do not compile the UVM yourself.

Comment: Surely actually using UVM 1.2 is hugely important for the review process?

Comment: There is a big difference between using UVM 1.2 in production versus experimenting with it. Too many times I've seen people starting out trying to use the latest and greatest only to realize that the VIP they need to integrate with is still on an older version. The lack of backward compatibility with the UVM is worse than what people are used to in other languages. My advice is to make sure your code works with both, and once the UVM is standardized with the IEEE, you can move forward.

Comment: Sensible advice, but this doesn't really answer the OP. As an aside, perhaps it should have been named UVM 2.0 if the incompatibility is that significant :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple bug in UVM12 to open the transaction database without honouring  a potential recording_detail setting. if recording is off then no db should be created (applies to text or vendor db)